# Strange content when extracting zipped manpage sources

Tags: man

For a little project at university if have to extract the zipped manpage sources, "nroff" them and parse the "nroffed" manpage for options, option arguments etc.. My script works just fine, except for some .gz files which don't contain the sources but instead something like

> .so /man1/bitmap.1

Is this some sort of link, or redirection or something? I couldn't find a thing on the net :-/.

Thanks in advance,

Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `.so` is, as you suggest, effectively a "symlink" to a different man page.  Depending on what you want to do, you can either ignore them or resolve the link.  To help you if you want to resolve the links, you can use `soelim`(1) to interpret the links for you (rather than doing it by hand).

Comment: I tried soelim but it doesn't seem to work, because he doesn't seem to find find the file the .so request points to.